# Как назначить одинаковое вращение для двух GameObject

Tags: c#, unity3d

Надо синхронизировать вращение фонарика и камеры, но при попытке дает ошибку:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class flashlightsync : MonoBehaviour
{
 // Variables
 GameObject camera;
 GameObject flashlight;

 // Function 4 sync camera pos y with pos y of main camera
 void FixedUpdate() {
     flashlight.transform.rotation.y = camera.transform.rotation.y;
         //тут ошибка
 }
}
```

Comment: уберите `.y` слева и справа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что нельзя изменить `rotation.x`, `rotation.y` или `rotation.z`. Можно только присвоить новый `rotation`.

```
void FixedUpdate() {
     flashlight.transform.rotation = camera.transform.rotation;
 }
```

p.s. Если нужно синхронизировать только по `y`, то можно сделать так:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
     flashlight.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(flashlight.transform.rotation.x, camera.transform.rotation.y, flashlight.transform.rotation.z, flashlight.transform.rotation.w);
}
```

Comment: Впредь буду внимательнее, спасибо!